# Get value of <s:select> in action class

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, combobox, action

I want to create combobox in JSP with Struts. My JSP page is:

```
<s:form id="form-sign-up" class="round styled" action="signUp" method="post" name="myForm" theme="xhtml" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label>Email:</label><input type="text" class="keyup-email text-input" name="7" value="" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <s:textfield name="fname" size="40" maxlength="40" required="true" key="your.FName-label"/>
    <s:textfield name="lname" size="40" maxlength="40" required="true" key="your.LName-label"/>
    <br />
    <s:set var="gender" value="{'male','female'}" />
    <s:select label="gender" name="gender"
              accesskey="" headerKey="-1" headerValue="I'm..." 
              cssClass="" list="gender"/>
    <br />          
    <s:password name="Pass" size="40" maxlength="40" required="true" key="your.Pass-label"/>
    <s:textarea name="job" label="Job" id="job" cols="32" rows="3" />
    <s:submit value="Submit" id="btn-submit" align="left"/>
</s:form>
```

now in my action I have:

```
public class SignUpAction  extends ActionSupport {

private String fname;
private String lname;
private String gender;
private String email;
private String pass;
private String job;
public static DataBase db ;

 @Override
public void validate(){
}

@Override
public String execute() throws Exception {

    DataBase db = new DataBase();
    try {
        User u1 = new User(fname,lname,gender,email,pass,job);
        db.Add_User(u1);

     } catch ( HibernateException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();

    }

    return SUCCESS;
}
... Getters and setters ...     
}
```

I want to get value of gender and save its value in my database but I can't get a value of `<s:select...` from JSP.

Comment: What's sent in the request? Also, watch out for "Pass" v. "pass".

Answer (score 0):

You can't get a value of  the list that have wrong type. To select the options values you need the list

```
List<String> gender;
```

to put the value you need the property

```
String yourGender;
```

and name the select tag with the property name

```
<s:select name="yourGender" list="gender"
```

make sure getters and setters both defined and after you submit if you are referencing default stack then `yourGender` will be set to your action.  The value is dependent on selection. So, you are free to choose the persistence framework or raw JDBC to save the value to the database.

Comment: You should mark it as accepted answer and upvote. The checkbox is on the left of the answer.